# Simple query without a specified field searching in whole ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-dsl

Say we have an ElasticSearch instance and one index. I now want to search the whole index for documents that contain a specific value. It's relevant to the search for this query over multiple fields, so I don't want to specify every field to search in.

My attempt so far (using NEST) is the following:

```
var res2 = client.Search<ElasticCompanyModelDTO>(s => s.Index("cvr-permanent").AllTypes().
     Query(q => q
        .Bool(bo => bo
            .Must( sh => sh
               .Term(c=>c.Value(query))
            )
         )
     ));
```

However, the query above results in an empty query:

I get the following output, `### ES REQEUST ### {}` , after applying the following debug on my connectionstring:

```
.DisableDirectStreaming()
.OnRequestCompleted(details =>
{
     Debug.WriteLine("### ES REQEUST ###");
     if (details.RequestBodyInBytes != null) Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes));
            })
 .PrettyJson();
```

How do I do this? Why is my query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var res2 = client.Search<ElasticCompanyModelDTO>(s => 
 s.Index("cvr-permanent").AllTypes()
.Query(qry => qry
   .Bool(b => b
   .Must(m => m
       .QueryString(qs => qs
           .DefaultField("_all")
           .Query(query))))));
```

Comment: Can you explain to the OP what the difference between using a `query_string` query here and a `term` query as in the original question is? I think it'll help better explain your answer :)

Comment: The Term query allows you to search against a specific field for an exact match at a time, while query_string query allows you to use match query against provided fields (_all being the combination of available fields). Does that sound close enough @RussCam? :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you must specify a single field to search as part of a TermQuery. In fact, all ElasticSearch queries require a field or fields to be specified as part of the query. If you want to search every field in your document, you can use the built-in "_all" field (unless you've disabled it in your mapping.)

You should be sure you really want a TermQuery, too, since that will only match exact strings in the text. This type of query is typically used when querying short, unanalyzed string fields (for example, a field containing an enumeration of known values like US state abbreviations.)

If you'd like to query longer full-text fields, consider the MultiMatchQuery (it lets you specify multiple fields, too.)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: The _all field was removed in ElasticSearch 6.0. There's a really good video from [ElasticOn](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2017/sf/elasticsearch-search-improvements) the remove _all starts around 07:30.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers rely on the presence of _all. In case anyone comes across this question at a later date, it is worth knowing that _all was removed in ElasticSearch 6.0

There's a really good video explaining the reasons behind this and the way the replacements work from [ElasticOn](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2017/sf/elasticsearch-search-improvements) starting at around 07:30 in.

In short, the _all query can be replaced by a simple_query_string and it will work with same way. The form for the _search API would be;

```
GET <index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "<queryTerm>"
    }
  }
}
```

The NEST pages on Elastic's documentation for this query are [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/simple-query-string-usage.html);